# ASP Net Core 3 Session (state) concurrency and integrity

Tags: asp.net-core, session-state

I have a page which requests multiple requests concurrently. So those requests are in the very same session. For accessing the session I use everywhere `IHttpContextAccessor`.

My problem is that regardless of the timing, some request does not see other requests already set session state, instead sees some previous state. (again in timing, the set state operation happened already, still)

As far as I know each requests has its own copy of the state, which is written back... (well "when"?) to the common "one" state. If this "when" is the delayed to when request is completely served, then the scenario what I experiencing is easily happen: The 2nd concurrent request within the session got his copy after the 1st request modified the state but before as it was finished completely.

However this all above means that in case of concurrent request serving within a session there is no way to maintain session integrity. The 2nd not seeing the already done changes by the 1st, will write back something what is not consistent with the already done 1st process change.

Am I missing something?
Is there any workaround? (with some cost of course)

Comment: Why do you need that one request should be able to "see" another request? Do you host one instance of application?

Comment: There is no need to see each others. However all requests make changes in the common state what must be consistent. Requests are not serialized (thank goodness) in a web server so this changes happen concurrently and not relying on the real current state will made inconsistencies in the state

Comment: ... as far as I see the whole implementation concept of the session state is supposing that requests within a session are serialized, which makes no sense in an async server architecture

Comment: How do you store your shared state in session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you may know this already, but it bears point out, just in case: session state is specific to one client. What you're talking about here, then, is the same client throwing multiple concurrent requests at the same time, each of which is touching the same piece of session state. That, in general, seems like a bad design. If there's some actual application reason to have multiple concurrent requests from the same client, then what those requests do should be idempotent or at least not step on each others toes. If it's a situation where the client is just spamming the server, either due to impatience or maliciousness, it's really not your concern whether their session state becomes corrupted as a result.

Second, because of the reasons outline above, concurrency is not really a concern for sessions. There's no use case I can imagine where the client would need to send multiple simultaneous requests that each modify the same session key. If there is, please elucidate by editing your question accordingly. However, I'd still imagine it would be something you likely shouldn't be persisting in the session in the first place.

That said, the session is thread-safe in that multiple simultaneous writes/reads will not cause an exception, but no guarantee is or can be made about integrity. That's universal across all concurrency scenarios. It's on you, as the developer, to ensure data integrity, if that's a concern. You do so, by designing a concurrency strategy. That could be anything from locks/semaphores to gate access or just compensating for things happening out of band. For example, with EF, you can employ concurrency tokens in your database tables to prevent one request overwriting another. The value of the token is modified with each successful update, and the application-known value is checked against the current database value before the update is made, to ensure that it has not been modified since the application initiated the update. If it has, then an exception is thrown to give the application a chance to catch and recover by cancelling the update, getting the fresh data and modifying that, or just pushing through an overwrite. This is to elucidate that you would need to come up with some sort of similar strategy if the integrity of the session data is important.